# How to modify the result of the mongo object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to return a modified object that has an parameter of an array is inside the module but the output doesnt result the modified object.

```
Test Modal
...
list: [String]
...
```

```
const tests = await Test.find();
tests.forEach(async(test, index) => {
      const invitations = await InvitationModel.find({test});
      invitations.forEach((invitation) => test.list.push({anon: index}));
})
return res.send(tests); //this returns the original tests in line one instead of modified tests that i did inside forEach.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a high order array method that returns array as a result, it doesn't modify the list cause it follow (the much needed) immutability principle.
Try this:

```
const tests = await Test.find();
const newTests = tests.forEach(async (test, index) => {
  const invitations = await InvitationModel.find({ test });
  test.list.push(invitations)
  return test
});
return res.send(newTests);
```

Not sure I pushed it like you wanted to but you get the idea. Also, note that you need to `return` when you use `forEach`.

Comment: This returns undefined for me for some reason